# Product discounted price in product page - Hybris Commerce 6.6

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have target discounted price for an SKU, with no product group or customer group filters, just a "target price" delimited by dates, that I want to show in the product page. This is maintained in the product management screen, and it's not promotions related.

As far as I can tell Hybris only calculates the discount when the product is placed in an order (the target price does show correctly in the cart page).

I tried creating a virtual cart in the product detail page, but unless I save the cart, Hybris doesn't allow me to calculate the discount. I don't want to save a cart each time a person goes into a product page.

What's the correct approach for this? Seems a pretty normal requirement.

Thank you

Comment: so you mean you are having a different price for some period due to an sale? like an additional priceRow with a timely limitation?

Comment: Yes. In the sku screen of backoffice you have two tables, one for the base price and the other one for discounts further down. The strange thing is that it appears in the cart correctly so it's being used as supposed too .... but just in the cart, the customer has no further visiblity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Price Rows with validity period (start and end date). Import all prices with validity date to system. List product prices in PDP on custom section with custom code.

Comment: Custom code. The top-tier Gartner Leader can't calculate the price after discounts in the standard system? I can understand if I need to develop a custom controller/JSP but I expect a ecommerce product to at least have an engine that calculates the price.

Answer (score 0):

A voucher/discount is applied to a cart, not to a product. Even if a voucher is only applicable for a specific product, hybris will only calculate a discount for an order/cart.

Comment: Why? It's quite normal for a retailer to have promotional prices that are applied without restrictions and they certainly want to show that discount in the product/search page without the person having to put the item into a cart. This is a very basic requirement that the solution should provide out of the box, especially the top-tier leader.

Comment: So you are looking for something like a "was $100, now for $90"?

Comment: Yes, which is quite normal in consumer retail.

Comment: Most times, the product is extended with an attribute "formerPrice" which is displayed next to the new price. Simplest solution I can give you.

Comment: In the end of the day I can develop this myself, what is baffling to me is how Hybris Commerce can be considered top-tier when so much has to be developed (this is not the first "normal" requirement that needs custom development). Seems like I'm licensing a framework instead of a solution.